# Visual Studio Packaging: Another version of this product is already installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, javascript

I have a msi created for a project which uses C# & Jscript. version-1.0 is currently public.  I want to release a bug-fixed version v-1.0.1 of this package but while testing it, I am getting "Another version of this product is already installed Installation of this version cannot continue.To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove program on the Control Panel".

I want this bug-fixed version to install silently without asking user to uninstall and install new one.
Please help me how can I achieve this, I am using visual studio 2008.

Thanks in Advance!

Sam

Update: I have tried changing the package code but that creates two instances of the package using same working directory. Visual Studio geeks please help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I would follow this process

In your main project

- Increment your Assembly Version no.

In your Visual Studio Setup project

- Set "Remove Previous Version" to true
- Increment the Version No. (this will
  change the product code for you too)

Comment: Incremented the assembly version no 
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.3.7")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.3.7")]
for the main component of the package. 
Set the "RemovePreviousVersion" to "8:TRUE"
Changed the version number to "1.0.3.7" from "0.0.28"
The problem still persists.

Comment: I did this for a service, which it replaced, and now fails to install because the service is already registered. But of course the installation of the new version rolled back and removed it from the add/remove programs so I can't uninstall the original. InstallUtil to the rescue!

Comment: Save my day. In my case, I need to install the same service to different name and different connection strings. I have different display name and service name for each project. Changing the version number helps.

Comment: Isn't it a good idea to delete all items from the registry that contains the name of the assembly?

Comment: In visual studio right clicking on the setup and choosing 'properties' is NOT the properties you want. You want to select the setup project and switch to the properties tab (or press F4).

Answer (score 16):

steps to solve the error:

1. Execute the following command from command prompt:

> msiexec /i program_name.msi /lv
>   logfile.log

where program_name.msi is the new version

/lv is log Verbose output

2. open up the logfile.log in the editor
3. find the GUID in the log

I found it in the following:

> Product Code from property table
>   before transforms: '{GUID}'

4. execute the msizap following command from the **visual studio command prompt** if you already have installed or get it from Microsoft website

   [Windows SDK Components for Windows Installer Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> msizap.exe TWP {GUID}

it did the trick and removed the installed service successfully.

Extract from 
[SOLVED]Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel][2](http://geekswithblogs.net/kazimmehdi/archive/2011/02/08/solvedanother-version-of-this-product-is-already-installed.-installation-of.aspx)

Comment: This worked for me.  Missed the part about "visual studio command prompt" at first, might be nice to bold that.

Comment: I used this for something non-VS related and you saved me hours of work.  You can also say msizap TW (MSI name) to zap all from that MSI package!

Answer (score 7):

You must specify the UpgradeCode and increment the ProductVersion to update a product. The UpgradeCode will remain the same for newer versions.

> The UpgradeCode property indicates a family of related applications consisting of different versions and different language versions of the same product.

This article explains the ProductCode, ProductVersion and UpgradeCode:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370837%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Following is what I have in my .vdproj file: 


"Name" = "8:Microsoft Visual Studio"
 "ProductCode" = "8:{8A3BC7ED-563E-42C1-ABEA-AAB14133E1AC}"
 "PackageCode" = "8:{24D081CF-EA46-4CA0-B3F7-D4DC60BC5FD8}"
 "UpgradeCode" = "8:{6F11B335-5F1E-4B4A-8565-6CCE50A8C599}"
...
"ProductVersion" = "8:0.0.26"

When I change the ProductVersion to "8:0.0.27" and build the msi. I still get the same 'Another version of this package....' message. 
Please Help!

Answer (score 4):

Open Setup Project Properties 
Click ProductCode .. New Code
Click UpgradeCode .. New Code
Rebuild and Install

Comment: Probably not a good idea since you'll end up with multiple versions of the same thing installed - you want it to detect and uninstall the previous version.