# . msi file fails with "Product :XXX Configuration failed" when called

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, windows-services, windows-installer

**Scenario 1:**
I run this code from a Windows Service and it fails with the windows event log:

> "Product: XXX -- Configuration failed"

**Scenario 2:**
I run this as a plain exe and it works.

Code I tried :

```
var installerFilePath = <Path of msi>;
System.Diagnostics.Process installerProcess;                       
installerProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(installerFilePath, " /q");
while (installerProcess.HasExited == false)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

I tried installing the Windows MSIInstaller extra logging but it didnt log anything.

Please advise.

KG

Comment: What makes you think you can install this package from session 0?

Comment: The suggested at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991286/visual-studio-packaging-another-version-of-this-product-is-already-installed fixed it

Comment: That topic does not talk about installing a package in session 0. Even if it is possible to install a package in session 0, you might not be able to install this one. What user does your service run as?

Comment: It run as local system account though. that should be good I thought ?

Comment: Well, all advice tells you not to run services as local system. What is this package that you install and why do it from a service? Some context might help.

Answer (score 0):

An msi is just a database. In your code, try calling `msiexec` with the appropriate parameters.

msiexec.exe is in your System32 directory. Open up a command prompt and type `msiexec /?` to get a list of parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I tried msiexec.exe using /qn /i parameters as well. It  had failed just as described above.

Comment: Looks like its installed in system account even though I uninstall from control panel.That seems to cause the issue."Another version of this product is already installed.  Installation of this version cannot continue."